# Cannot edit Pivot Table Style

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table, styles

I'm trying to modify my custom PivotTable style in Excel 2013. However, when I right-click my custom style, and select **Modify**, nothing happens. Normally I'd expect the **Modify PivotTable Style** selection box to appear.

I've tried restarting Excel, and even rebooting completely, but that makes no difference. I tried creating a brand new custom style and modifying that, but still no success.

Never had this problem before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trawling around the web, it seems the problem is [caused by protected worksheets](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting-and-pivots/1083840-cant-edit-or-delete-custom-pivot-table-styles.html). If any worksheet in the workbook is protected you aren't able to edit PivotTable styles.

This workbook is one I inherited, so I checked each tab in turn - eventually I found a hidden sheet that had been protected. I wasn't using it so deleted it! Problem solved! I can now modify my style.

However - if I needed to keep the sheet and *didn't know the password to unprotect it*, I don't believe there would be a way to edit my PivotTable style. The only way to do so would be to create an entirely new sheet, copy the functionality of my protected sheet across and then delete the original. And copying the functionality may not be possible if the sheet protection blocks you from selecting cells (because you can't see the formulas to replicate them).